# SharePoint 2013 "Content Viewing" audit report takes forever to "working on it"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I'm in a SP2013 environment. I enabled audit and then configured audit settings in the site collection, waited for 2 days. Now, if I go to View Auditing Reports under the site collection, I can see the list of the reports. However, for some reasons, except the "Content Viewing", all other reports can be generated quickly and shown correctly. The "Content Viewing" takes forever to generate. Actually, it never ends, always shown as "Working on it. This shouldn't take long". The report is configured to generate in a document library. "Content Viewing" is never in it too.

However, if I use Custom report, check event "Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties", the custom report is generated quickly.

In configuration, Auto Trim is "yes", the report retention is "3" (yes, 3. just for testing). However, the "Content Viewing" still shows "Working on it. This shouldn't take long". And there is no error message.

My question is: what can cause this? permission (my account is local admin and farm admin)? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately is not available in SP Online. I've been looking for solution 1 year mow.
Opened and downloaded documents, viewed items in lists, or viewed item properties (This event is not available for SharePoint Online sites)
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102772739.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Finally Microsoft  made the appropriate updates/upgrades, and all audit logs are available on 2016/365 under Admin Center-> Security & Compliance -> Search & Investigation. Excellent Feature for Audit, eDiscovery, Policies, Security, Data Governance, in compliance with ISO 27001 and DOD.